# C# General Question about Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to add a label the following way

```
public partial class _base : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblText.Text ="Hello";
    }
}
```

}

The problem is it is telling Object reference not set to an intance of an object. This is the code behind my MasterPage.cs.

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

In master page

Comment: If this is asp.net related you should tag it as such.

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare lblText? Does it have a runat attribute with a value of server.

Comment: Way ahead of you, Chris. :) @user710502, please show us where `lblText` is declared.

Comment: where is the "lblText" control? Is it in the Master page or on another page which uses the Master page?

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating a new master page type, as opposed to just creating a page that uses the master page.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want

Comment: It is in the masterpage in a ContentPlaceHolder with id="Top"

Comment: In your masterpage aspx file, what class does it inherit? It should be Inherits="_base"

Comment: Are you sure that the error message comes from this line?

Comment: I think the real question is, why I can not access lblText.Text = "Hello" in the masterpage code behind?

Comment: Yes it comes from this line as when I take it out it does not complain

Comment: Since you are defining `lblText` in the XML, then it makes no sense that you are getting a null reference exception. Since the compiler can see the `lblText` variable, there must be no problem with its declaration. The control is either not getting created, or the variable is being set to null. Something strange is going on here. I think we're gonna need more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your code has

```
Label lblText;
```

you should put

```
Label lblText = new Label();
```

instead. This will make the error go away, because then an actual instance of the label control will be referenced by the `lblText` variable. But the label will not show up until you also add

```
 Controls.Add(lblText);
```

to your page load event.

Alternatively, you could add the label to your page as @amonteiro suggests. Then you could put it in a location that makes sense for the rest of your application.

Comment: How can I control where to place it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find lblText in your page because it's not part of the page's class. It's part of the master page's class. You have to find it in the master page like so:

```
Label lblText = (Label) Master.FindControl("lblText")};
```

Also, [don't use a Label if a Literal will do the trick](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx).

Edit: Just realized I might have read your question wrong. If you're trying to find it in the code behind for the Master page itself, then my answer does not apply.